ExtJS nested binding
I'm using ExtJS 7.5.1
Need to bind
I have custom Combobox
Ext.define('vkr.components.comboboxes.DepartmentCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    ......
    departmentTypeId: null,
    bind: {
        store: '{cathedra}'
    },
    setDepartmentTypeId: function (value) {
        this.departmentTypeId = value;
    },
});

ViewModel
Ext.define('vkr.components.DepartmentComboViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.department_combo',
    formulas: {
        departmentTypeId: {
            get: function(get) {
                return this.getView().departmentTypeId;
            }
        },
    },
    stores: {
        cathedra: {
            .......
            proxy: {
                ......
                extraParams: {
                    department_type_id: "{departmentTypeId}"
                }
            }
        },
    }
});

I need to bind departmentTypeId from panel, which gets value from viewmodel data.
{
    xtype: "department_combo",
    name: "department_id",
    bind: {
        departmentTypeId: "{department_type_id}",
    },
},

Parameter binded before window.show method colled (panel in the window)
win.getViewModel().notify();
win.getViewModel().set("department_type_id", department_type_id);
win.getViewModel().notify();

So in combobox viewmodel departmentTypeId is null, I think because Ext tries bind parameter before win.getViewModel().notify() called. How can I set the departmentTypeId parameter value correctly

My solution is add "render" listener and set viewmodel data value from onRender function
onRender: function () {
    this.lookupReference(
        "PreviousDepartment"
    ).getViewModel().set(
        "departmentTypeId", this.getViewModel().get("department_type_id")
    );
},


The main problem is, that you create a formula in the ViewModel, which runs on creating the viewmodel. It will never re-run, because there is no binding inside the formula.
formulas: {
    name: {
        bind: '{someData}',
        get: function(data) {
            // without binding will run once on creating!
            
            // rund only when `someData` binding changes,
            // will not run until changes from null or undefined to value
        }
    }
}

Without any binding it will run initially, but never again.
At that point departmentTypeId is not set.
Your view waits for the setter, which seems not to be called.
departmentTypeId: null,
// never been called
setDepartmentTypeId: function (value) {
    this.departmentTypeId = value;
},

Once you call setDepartmentTypeId, you would set the departmentTypeId (but too late for the formula).
A better way would be to auto-create a setter, getter, apply and update:
config: {
    // creates a set-, get-, apply-, updateDepartmentTypeId
    departmentTypeId: null
},

// you might want to add these lines
updateDepartmentTypeId: function(value) {
    this.getViewModel().set('departmentTypeId', value);
}

The config will add a setter and the update function, which I use here to populate the viewModel data-binding.
Personally I would not set a data-binding to fullfill a store extraParam data-binding, because it is too expansive. I would do this:
config: {
    departmentTypeId: null
},

// you might want to add these lines
updateDepartmentTypeId: function(value) {
    let store  = this.getViewModel().getStore('cathedra');

    // set the extraParams
    store.getProxy().setExtraParams({
        departmentTypeId: value
    });
    // do not autoLoad the store
    store.load();
}

